# How to save facebook user score and get (top 10) Facebook friends High Score?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, parse-platform, unity-game-engine, leaderboard

I'm using **parse.com** to save my game score. I'm also using Facebook sdk in my game. In my game there is two leader-board that's why I'm using **parse.com** to save users and user's friends score. But Don't know how to get top 10 Facebook friends high score and how to save Facebook user score.

Answer (score 0):

1. You need to use [Facebook SDK for Unity](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/unity) to get user's and friends' profile data.
2. Create an Object for **Player** at Parse using  [This Guide](https://parse.com/docs/unity/guide).
3. Save friends ids as comma separated string as an field of Player table.
4. Retrieve all of friends data using Parse Queries given in guide. use this query to sort by score:

   ```
   var query = ParseObject.GetQuery("GameScore")
   .OrderBy("score")
   .ThenByDescending("playerName");
   ```